# S3 file added including some tags. S3:ObjectTagging:Put event is also triggered?

Tags: amazon-s3, s3-object-tagging

when an S3 file is added to a bucket including some tags **createObject** event is triggered. What about **s3:ObjectTagging:Put** , is also triggered ?

I am thinking of implementing some workflow bases on tags handling and want to track file from beginning with same **EventBridge** rule.

Answer (score 0):

No, `s3:ObjectTagging:Put` is not triggered when you create an object with tags.

> The `s3:ObjectTagging:Put` event type notifies you when **a tag is PUT on an object** or **an existing tag is updated**.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I hadn't the chance to test that by myself. I was expecting that event triggered as well because ObjectTagging:Put permission is required when uploading a file with tags.